# Toggle class in closest parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, toggleclass

So I have this jquery that i need to make it work. But through all the parents() and children(), I can't get to where I want.

My objective is when I click in the button, the class icon-cross, toggle to icon-tick.

(In this snippet bellow, I made an example to explain better. In this case I want to change the color of the rectangle)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".addOpt").click(function(e) {
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      return text === "Add" ? "Remove" : "Add";
    });
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-primary btn-remove");
    
    
    //the problem is the following line:
    $(this).closest(".quoteCompare").children(".quoteCompareInside").p.toggleClass("icon-tick icon-cross");
    
    
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

```css
.icon-cross {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.icon-tick {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="medium-6 xsmall-12 small-12 column quoteCompare  ">
    <div class="quoteCompareInside quoteStandard sameHeight2">
      <p class="icon-cross"></p>
      <p class="title noMarginBottom">10€</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-6 xsmall-12 small-12 column quoteCompare  ">
    <div class="quoteCompareInside quoteStandard sameHeight2">
      <div class="form-row valign">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary buttonOpt addOpt">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take `p` as selector, not as property:

```
$(this).closest(".quoteCompare").children(".quoteCompareInside").find('p').toggleClass("icon-tick icon-cross");
```

If you want to get only 1st `p` element you can use [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method:

```
$(this).closest(".quoteCompare").children(".quoteCompareInside").find('p').eq(0).toggleClass("icon-tick icon-cross");
```

*Edit:*

Note that closest `quoteCompare` will return second div with classes `medium-6 xsmall-12 small-12 column quoteCompare`, so you probably also should use [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) in your code:

```
$(this).closest(".quoteCompare").prev().children(".quoteCompareInside").find('p').eq(0).toggleClass("icon-tick icon-cross");
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".addOpt").click(function(e) {
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      return text === "Add" ? "Remove" : "Add";
    });
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-primary btn-remove");
    
    
    //the problem is the following line:
    $(this).closest(".quoteCompare").prev().children(".quoteCompareInside").find('p').eq(0).toggleClass("icon-tick icon-cross");
    
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

```css
.icon-cross {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.icon-tick {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="medium-6 xsmall-12 small-12 column quoteCompare  ">
    <div class="quoteCompareInside quoteStandard sameHeight2">
      <p class="icon-cross"></p>
      <p class="title noMarginBottom">10€</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-6 xsmall-12 small-12 column quoteCompare  ">
    <div class="quoteCompareInside quoteStandard sameHeight2">
      <div class="form-row valign">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary buttonOpt addOpt">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, we are getting there but still not working.

Comment: @groseler see my updated answer with snippet, you should also call `prev` on `$(this).closest(".quoteCompare")`

Comment: Perfect. So that was the problem. I've done what you said and it works smoothly. Thank you! 5*

Answer (score 1):

You can include the `p` in the `children()` selector:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".addOpt").click(function(e) {
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      return text === "Add" ? "Remove" : "Add";
    });
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-primary btn-remove");


    //the problem is the following line:
     $(this).closest(".quoteCompare").children(".quoteCompareInside p").toggleClass("icon-tick icon-cross");


    e.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

```css
.icon-cross {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.icon-tick {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="medium-6 xsmall-12 small-12 column quoteCompare  ">
    <div class="quoteCompareInside quoteStandard sameHeight2">
      <p class="icon-cross"></p>
      <p class="title noMarginBottom">10€</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-6 xsmall-12 small-12 column quoteCompare  ">
    <div class="quoteCompareInside quoteStandard sameHeight2">
      <div class="form-row valign">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary buttonOpt addOpt">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your snippet but its not working. But its another way to do it (adding the selector inside). Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

We need to traverse to `<div class="row">` to grab the associated `<p>` tag. Please have a look at below snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".addOpt").click(function(e) {
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      return text === "Add" ? "Remove" : "Add";
    });
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-primary btn-remove");


    //the problem is the following line:
    if($(this).text() === "Remove")
      $(this).closest(".row").find("p.icon-cross").toggleClass("icon-tick icon-cross");
    else
      $(this).closest(".row").find("p.icon-tick").toggleClass("icon-tick icon-cross");


    e.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

```css
.icon-cross {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.icon-tick {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="medium-6 xsmall-12 small-12 column quoteCompare  ">
    <div class="quoteCompareInside quoteStandard sameHeight2">
      <p class="icon-cross"></p>
      <p class="title noMarginBottom">10€</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-6 xsmall-12 small-12 column quoteCompare  ">
    <div class="quoteCompareInside quoteStandard sameHeight2">
      <div class="form-row valign">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary buttonOpt addOpt">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, another interesting way to do it! :)

Comment: Thanks @groseler...!